# making tablix row disappear if there is no value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm working on SSRS report which looks like this:

[image]

So what's happening is here I have 2 rows of detail in Yellow and in Red. The row with EXPR right under the RED line is the Totals.

In every case, i will need to have the YELLOW row of data, but there are times that I don't have data in RED Row but I still always need to display the TOTALS row (right under RED line)

I am able to successfully hide the textboxes in TextBox Properties --> visibility. I also set the same thing for Row Visibility (RED row)

The problem is -- if I have no data in RED row, all textboxes get hidden, but I still have a gap, and I'm hoping there is a way to get rid of it, so the EXPR below RED line moves up and is right below the YELLOW line.

Any ideas? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the RED row visibility to hidden, not the visibility of each individual text box.

If visible, the row will take up space even when all contained controls are hidden.

If hidden, the row will not be drawn and the space reclaimed to the parent container.